# Does Shaimos’s sanctity applied to sculpted names

Tags: halacha, shemos-sacred-names, writing-printing, yoreh-deah, genizah-storage

There is a prohibition in Halacha of erasing one of the Hebrew names of Hashem, known as Shaimos. My question is whether this only applies to normally written or printed names or also names sculpted into an object. For example if someone decided to sculpt the Tetragrammaton into a rock, would that rock require disposal in Geniza or could you destroy it?

Comment: https://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=1&hilchos=1&perek=6&halocha=6